# Scala | what is the difference between '<-', '->' and '=>' operators and how do they work implicitly?

Tags: scala, scala-collections

While studying basic of Scala I came across "<-" operator which they say is a generator from any range/list or collection.

1. On what basis it generates the values and what may be the way to do that implicitly?
2. Is compulsory to take a main() in Object.scala? Can't I define a main() in a Class.scala?
3. Is compulsory to make an Object.scala to take the output from the methods of a class?

Comment: That is a lot of questions, many of which have nothing to do with each other and should be separate. Many, if not all have been answered already.

Comment: Just tell me the answer if u know....sir..

Comment: `<-`, `->` and `=>` are completely different things used in completely different places, the only similarity that they have is that they all look like arrows.

Comment: @Jesper thanks for telling that sir but can you provide me a link where I can really differentiate them?

Comment: @yashpalbharadwaj You should open new questions (or find existing ones) for your 2 and 3 questions. Stick to one question per post as it's a Q&A site, not a forum

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Arrows

`<-`, `->` and `=>` are completely different things with completely different uses in Scala - it doesn't make a lot of sense to compare them.

`<-` is used in `for` comprehensions. On the right side of the `<-` is a generator, which is an instance of a type with a `foreach` method, which generates the elements that the `for` is going to loop over. Note that the generator does not need to be a collection - anything that has a `foreach` method will work (it can for example be an `Option`).

`->` is a method that creates a tuple. This method is often used when creating a `Map` with a convenient, readable syntax. For example:

```
val map = Map("one" -> 1, "two" -> 2, "three" -> 3)
```

Note that `"one" -> 1` is the same as `("one", 1)` (a `Tuple2` containing the values `"one"` and `1`), etc.

`=>` is used in function literals and function types, it's the separator between the function's (or function type's) arguments and body (or return type).

### main()

Scala doesn't have `static` like Java. Anything that you would make `static` in Java, you would put in an `object` instead of in a `class` in Scala.

Since the `main()` method should be `static`, it must be defined in an `object` in Scala instead of in a class.

Ofcourse you could create a `main()` method in a class, but you cannot use this as the entry point of an application - it would just be a regular method that happens to be named `main`.

Comment: `<-` is used for `map`/`flatMap` as well as `foreach`

Comment: @Daenyth And `collect`

Comment: I've seen <- used outside of a for loop, so this answer needs to be updated